# Usage of Spark DataFrame.flatMap in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, flatmap

I have worked with RDD.flatMap function in java. Now trying my hands on DataFrames.

They say:

```
public <R> RDD<R> flatMap(scala.Function1<org.apache.spark.sql.Row,
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce<R>> f, scala.reflect.ClassTag<R> evidence$4)
```

> Returns a new RDD by first applying a function to all rows of this
>   DataFrame, and then flattening the results.
>
> Specified by:
>       flatMap in interface RDDApi

But when I tried this, `Function1`, is forcing me to override lots and lots of unimplemented methods. This is what I get:

```
    RDD<Row> res = df.flatMap(new Function1<Row, TraversableOnce<Row>>() {

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Row, A> andThen(
                Function1<TraversableOnce<Row>, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcDD$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcDF$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcDI$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcDJ$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcFD$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcFF$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcFI$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcFJ$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcID$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcIF$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcII$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcIJ$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcJD$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcJF$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcJI$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcJJ$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcVD$sp(
                Function1<BoxedUnit, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcVF$sp(
                Function1<BoxedUnit, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcVI$sp(
                Function1<BoxedUnit, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcVJ$sp(
                Function1<BoxedUnit, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcZD$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcZF$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcZI$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<Object, A> andThen$mcZJ$sp(
                Function1<Object, A> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public TraversableOnce<Row> apply(Row arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public double apply$mcDD$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public double apply$mcDF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public double apply$mcDI$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public double apply$mcDJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float apply$mcFD$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float apply$mcFF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float apply$mcFI$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float apply$mcFJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int apply$mcID$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int apply$mcIF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int apply$mcII$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int apply$mcIJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long apply$mcJD$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long apply$mcJF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long apply$mcJI$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long apply$mcJJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void apply$mcVD$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void apply$mcVF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void apply$mcVI$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void apply$mcVJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply$mcZD$sp(double arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply$mcZF$sp(float arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply$mcZI$sp(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply$mcZJ$sp(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, TraversableOnce<Row>> compose(
                Function1<A, Row> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcDD$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcDF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcDI$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcDJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcFD$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcFF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcFI$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcFJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcID$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcIF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcII$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcIJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcJD$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcJF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcJI$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcJJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, BoxedUnit> compose$mcVD$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, BoxedUnit> compose$mcVF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, BoxedUnit> compose$mcVI$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, BoxedUnit> compose$mcVJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcZD$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcZF$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcZI$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public <A> Function1<A, Object> compose$mcZJ$sp(
                Function1<A, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }, evidence$4);
```

This looks weird, but I went on to make `evidence$4` as:

```
ClassTag<Row> evidence$4 = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Row.class);
```

My intention is to just play around with `flatMap` (of-course on DataFrames not on RDD). So I don't need any changes on `Row`. Can return the input as is without any changes.

So I guess I need to make change only in `apply` method.

```
    @Override
    public TraversableOnce<Row> apply(Row arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

But again, how should I get `TraversableOnce<Row>` from `Row`?

Also, is the method I am trying correct? Or am I missing something?

I am using Apache Spark 1.3.1

Comment: First of all, you should use the [`scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1) in the function. You can create `TraversableOnce` from Java collections too with the [`scala.collection.JavaConverters$`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$).

Comment: Please, remove "spark-java" tag, it's not related to Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like the following:

```java
RDD<Row> res = df.flatMap(new AbstractFunction1<Row, TraversableOnce<Row>>() {
  public TraversableOnce<Row> apply(Row row) {
    return new ListSet<Row>().$plus(row); //Note the updated list is returned from $plus()
  }
}, evidence$4);
```

This would work similarly to `map`, just with more freedom to change. For example to filter out things, you could return the empty `new ListSet<Row>()` when you want to return it, or keep with the current behaviour. `flatMap` is very flexible.

(It seems the conversion from Java collections is not trivial to Scala collections.)

Comment: In my mind, DataFrame = RDD + Schema. 

If that is the case, essentially what we should be doing is

newDF = DF.RDD.flatmap(f).applySchema(), without getting to much trouble of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Is that it?? Isn't there any change under the hood? Will the performance be just the same?

Comment: @gábor-bakos, tried exactly same code from your answer. It shows compilation error and asks me to "Add cast to 'TraversableOnce<Row>' ". Tried that, but getting exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Decorators$AsScala cannot be cast to scala.collection.TraversableOnce".

Comment: Let's add a `toList()` to that in that case.

Comment: Where do I add `toList()`? (Sorry but this scala - java thing is confusing). Can you please post the updated code? Also what is "evidence$4"? What purpose it serves? Is the way I made it up correct? Is there a good documentation of Spark DF java apis with examples?

Comment: Just noticed that you had edited your answer. But this `JavaConverters$.MODULE$.asScalaBufferConverter(Collections.singletonList(row)).toList();` gives _"The method toList() is undefined for the type Decorators.AsScala<Buffer<Row>>"_    I am using spark 1.3.1

Comment: Sorry, these are beyond my current knowledge from using Scala collections from Java. The `evidence$4` could be named differently, I just tried to add what you suggested, in Scala that is automatically populated.
 Maybe putting `List.apply` around the list: `List$.MODULE$.apply(JavaConverters$.MODULE$.asScalaBufferConverter(Collections.singletonList(row)))` would fix the error. Or `List$.MODULE$.apply(new Row[]{row})` might also work.

Comment: Both didn't work. But this did: `ListSet<Row> b = new ListSet<Row>(); b.$plus(row); return b;`. But I am getting 0 records in output. My doubt is on the `evidence$4`. Any help?

Comment: Yeah, I think `$plus` returns the collection containing the row, so this might work: `ListSet<Row> b = new ListSet<Row>().$plus(row); return b;`.

Comment: Ooops! Thats it. `ListSet<Row> b = new ListSet<Row>().$plus(row);` is giving output. problem was that separate `b.$plus(row);` which was not assigned back to b. Please modify your answer. I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer, this was educational for me too. Thank you.