# SparkSQL + Java: Pojo to Tabular Format while working with Datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm pretty new to Spark SQL. While implementing one of training tasks I faced the following issue and could not find an answer (all the following examples are a bit dumb, but should be still ok for demonstration purposes).

My app reads a parquet file and creates a dataset basing on its content:

```
DataFrame input = sqlContext.read().parquet("src/test/resources/integration/input/source.gz.parquet");
Dataset<Row> dataset = input.as(RowEncoder$.MODULE$.apply(input.schema()));
```

The dataset.show() call results in:

```
+------------+----------------+--------+
+    Names   +       Gender   +   Age  +
+------------+----------------+--------+
| Jack, Jill |  Male, Female  | 30, 25 |
```

Then I convert the dataset into a new dataset with the Person type inside:

```
public static Dataset<Person> transformToPerson(Dataset<Row> rawData) {
    return rawData
            .flatMap((Row sourceRow) -> {
                // code to parse an input row and split person data goes here
                Person person1 = new Person(name1, gender1, age1);
                Person person2 = new Person(name2, gender2, age2);
                return Arrays.asList(person1, person2);
            }, Encoders.bean(Person.class));
}
```

where

```
public abstract class Human implements Serializable {
   protected String name;
   protected String gender;
   // getters/setters go here
   // default constructor + constructor with the name and gender params
 }
 public class Person extends Human {
   private String age;
   // getters/setters for the age param go here
   // default constructor + constructor with the age, name and gender params
   // overriden toString() method which returns the string: (<name>, <gender>, <age>)
 }
```

Finally, when I show the dataset's content I expect to see

```
 +------------+----------------+--------+
 +    name    +       gender   +   age  +
 +------------+----------------+--------+
 |     Jack   |     Male       |   30   |
 |     Jill   |     Femail     |   25   |
```

However, I see

```
+-------------------+----------------+--------+
+      name         +       gender   +   age  +
+-------------------+----------------+--------+
|(Jack, Male, 30)   |                |        |
|(Jill, Femail, 25) |                |        |
```

Which is a result of the toString() method, while the header is correct.
I believe something is wrong with the Encoder, as far as if I use the Encoders.javaSerizlization(T) or Encoders.kryo(T) it shows

```
+------------------+
+        value     +
+------------------+
|(Jack, Male, 30)  |
|(Jill, Femail, 25)|
```

What worries me most is maybe the incorrect usage of encoders could result in incorrect SerDe and/or performance penalties.
I cannot not see anything special in all Spark Java examples that I can find...

Could you please suggest what I do wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

Here are my project's dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**SOLUTION**

As abaghel suggested I upgraded the version to 2.0.2 (please be aware that on version 2.0.0 there is [the bug for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940312/why-does-spark-report-java-net-urisyntaxexception-relative-path-in-absolute-ur)), used Dataset instead of DataFrames everywhere in my code (seems like DataFrames are not a part of Apache Spark [starting from 2.0.0](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector/issues/36)), and used the iterator-based flatMap function to transform from Row to Person.

Just to share, the approach of using the [TraversableOnce-based flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440567/usage-of-spark-dataframe-flatmap-in-java) for version 1.6.2 did not work for me as it threw the 'MyPersonConversion$function1 not Serializable' exception.

Now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of Spark you are using? Method for flatMap you have provided is not compiling with version 2.2.0. Return type required is `Iterator<Person>`. Please use below FlatMapFunction and you will get the desired output.

```
public static Dataset<Person> transformToPerson(Dataset<Row> rawData) {
    return rawData.flatMap(row -> {
        String[] nameArr = row.getString(0).split(",");
        String[] genArr = row.getString(1).split(",");
        String[] ageArr = row.getString(2).split(",");
        Person person1 = new Person(nameArr[0], genArr[0], ageArr[0]);
        Person person2 = new Person(nameArr[1], genArr[1], ageArr[1]);
        return Arrays.asList(person1, person2).iterator();
    }, Encoders.bean(Person.class));
}

//Call function
Dataset<Person> dataset1 = transformToPerson(dataset);
dataset1.show();
```

Comment: abaghel, thank you! Please see the 'update 1' in the original question: I added the details

Comment: Thanks for the update @Dmitry. It looks like there is some issue with bean encoder in Spark 1.6.2 version. Please try with Spark version 2.0 and above.